# Strange equality

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I didn't understand why in Fulton's book, the author says that $k(X)=k(V)$, I can't understand why the field of rational function on $X$ are equal to the field of the rational functions on whole $V$.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A definition doesn't need a reason, but it can be more natural or less natural. This one is very natural. The idea behind it is that $X$, being open in (the Zariski topology of) $V$ (and being nonempty --- tacitly assumed here) is  a very large part of $V$, so large that a rational function on $V$ is completely determined by its restriction to $X$.  So the field of rational functions on $V$ is isomorphic to the field of restrictions to $X$ of those rational functions.  It is natural to call those restrictions the rational functions on $X$.  Identifying rational functions on $V$ with their restrictions to $X$ (which is reasonable since the algebraic formula for a function is unchanged by restriction) leads to the identification of $k(X)$ with $k(V)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just to translate Andreas Blass' excellent answer formally: one has (at least) two possibilities to define the field of rational functions $k(Y)$ of a (integral) variety $Y$.

1. Define $k(Y)$ as $k(U)=\textrm{Frac}\,\mathcal O_Y(U)$, where $U$ is any affine open subset of $Y$. (This requires the (easy) proof that $k(Y)$ is well-defined.)
2. Define $k(Y)=\varinjlim_{U\subset Y}\mathcal O_Y(U)$, where $U$ runs the directed system of nonempty open subsets of $Y$.

The first definition is the one you have encountered, and the previous answer explains very well why it is a reasonable definition.

From the second definition, we can actually deduce the equality $k(X)=k(V)$, where $X\subset V$ is an open part:

$$k(X)=\varinjlim_{W\subset X}\mathcal O_X(W)=\varinjlim_{U\subset V}\mathcal O_X(U\cap X)=\varinjlim_{U\subset V}\mathcal O_V(U)=k(V).$$